# Why Yosef became the king of Egypt?

Tags: malchut-royalty, yosef, egypt

Why H'shem chose specifically Yosef to become the king of Egypt and not another brother? Wasn't it more suitable to Yehuda, for instance, who already represented the "Malchut" of Israel, or to Reuven, the oldest one? What was the main characteristic he had that the others did not?

Comment: Because Yosef was the one who was there in situ (Yosef was sold into slavery) and worked his way up to become leader. The other brothers only came down to Egypt when there was a famine and they needed food.

Comment: Joseph was king of Egypt?

Comment: My point is: why H'shem chose specifically him to go through all this and not another brother? What was the main characteristic he had that the others did not?

Comment: His ability to interpret dreams. It was this that made the brother jealous and sell him, and it helped him interpret his fellow inmates' dreams in jail, and finally what made him be called upon to interpret Paroah's dream which elevated him to a position of power.

Comment: R Manis Friedman, based on chassidus, says that the main disagreement between Yosef and the brothers was they brothers thought the jewish path is the "shepherd", i.e. hermit, away from the world, and Yosef said that no, we must engaged with the world and make it holy. "Let's see what will become of your dreams" was the fortuitous statement that was the purpose of Yosef's descent, in order to engage with the unholy world to make it holy and demonstrate/start the jewish path to fixing the world.

Comment: As per @RabbiKaii, Yosef channels the world to *avodas Hashem* because he is the *tzadik yesod olam*.